# задача по программированию timus online judge №1005, python

Tags: python

Текст задачи: у вас есть несколько камней известного веса w1, …, wn. Напишите программу, которая распределит камни в две кучи так, что разность весов этих двух куч будет минимальной.

```
n = int(input())
s = input()
new = s.split(' ')
A = []
sum_ = 0
for i in new:
    A.append(int(i))
    sum_ = sum_ + int(i)
A = sorted(A)
include = [0] * n
l_len = n
r_len = 0
l_sum = sum_
r_sum = 0
diff_before = sum_
while True:
    if l_sum > r_sum:
        for i in range(n-1):
            if include[i] == 0 and abs((l_sum - A[i]) - (r_sum + A[i])) < abs(l_sum - r_sum): 
                include[i] = 1
                l_sum -=A[i]
                r_sum += A[i]
    elif r_sum > l_sum:
        for i in range(n-1):
            if include[i] == 1 and abs((r_sum - A[i]) - (l_sum + A[i])) < abs(l_sum - r_sum): 
                include[i] = 0
                r_sum -=A[i]
                l_sum += A[i]
    diff_after = abs(l_sum - r_sum)
    if diff_before == diff_after or diff_after == 0:
        break
    elif diff_after < diff_before:
        diff_before = diff_after
a = int(abs(l_sum - r_sum))
print(a)
```

Смысл программы примерно такой:
    для каждого камня из большей кучи:
        переложить в меньшую число, если разница куч сократится
        иначе ничего не делать
    если разница куч после цикла сократилась, то повторить цикл.
Из всех тестов, что я пробовал, программа дает правильный ответ,а при проверке на timus результат не верный. В чем здесь может быть ошибка?
Пробовал выполнить программу методом DP: создавал таблицу n * максимальное_число, но по времени не проходило решение

Comment: Решение из 17 строчек через рекурсию: сначала все камни в одной кучке, а затем перекидываете камни в другую кучку и смотрите суммы. Камней немного, поэтому можно смело так делать

Comment: Подсказка: нас не интересуют кучки, нас интересует их сумма, точнее разность, поэтому работу с массивами ограничиваем по минимуму и работаем только с суммами, тогда по времени будет проходить

Answer (score 1):

Вот на этом тесте валится:

```
8
6 7 9 13 18 24 31 50
```

Твоя программа выдает 4, ответ 0 = 50 + 9 + 13 + 7 - 6 - 24 - 18 - 31.

Есть по этой задаче вот такое обсуждение ["Две кучки камней"](http://acmp.ru/asp/gb.asp?page2=1&id=71&page=1), сама задача попроще немного, там упоминаются решения через "двоичную систему", проще говоря, перебором по вариантам раскладки камней. Для 20 камней должна успеть проходить, хотя вариантов 1М. Возможно, имеет смысл как-то оптимизировать перебор, а может, и в лоб в лимит времени влезет.